# need some explanation. why are these two expressions equal?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, proof-explanation, orthogonality

I understand the whole proof but one thing

why are the expressions in red boxes equal ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply because $\left<x_{k},x_{n}\right>=\delta_{k,n}$ which equals to $1$ if $k=n$, $0$ if $k\ne n$, and the assumption that $\{x_{n}\}$ is orthogonal.

Comment: I should've guessed that myself.
I think I have to quickly review some background material before continuing.
thanks for the clarification btw